# Object sorting as per the sequence number with javascript

Tags: javascript

It can be poosible get an object as per the custom sequence.
when we are trying to sort this object as per the sequence number it will updated in the alphanumeric sequence.

Please suggest if is there any solution for the same.

**Input**:

```
{
    "62b375bc-9125-4609-a0be-08db58396efb": {
        "sequenceNumber": 3,
        "id": "62b375bc-9125-4609-a0be-08db58396efb",
        "originalSequence": 1
    },
    "e7921939-2d6c-4366-483f-08db5f9a5388": {
        "sequenceNumber": 1,
        "id": "e7921939-2d6c-4366-483f-08db5f9a5388",
        "originalSequence": 2
    },
    "b7f12783-b0a0-4689-6cfd-08dbf0b89242": {
        "sequenceNumber": 2,
        "id": "b7f12783-b0a0-4689-6cfd-08dbf0b89242",
        "originalSequence": 4
    },
    "de0c0a68-bf7a-4048-6cfe-08dbf0b89242": {
        "sequenceNumber": 4,
        "id": "de0c0a68-bf7a-4048-6cfe-08dbf0b89242",
        "originalSequence": 5,
    }
}
```

**Expected Output** (sorting as per the sequence number):

```
{
    "e7921939-2d6c-4366-483f-08db5f9a5388": {
        "sequenceNumber": 1,
        "id": "e7921939-2d6c-4366-483f-08db5f9a5388",
        "originalSequence": 2
    },
    "b7f12783-b0a0-4689-6cfd-08dbf0b89242": {
        "sequenceNumber": 2,
        "id": "b7f12783-b0a0-4689-6cfd-08dbf0b89242",
        "originalSequence": 4
    },
    "62b375bc-9125-4609-a0be-08db58396efb": {
        "sequenceNumber": 3,
        "id": "62b375bc-9125-4609-a0be-08db58396efb",
        "originalSequence": 1
    },     
    "de0c0a68-bf7a-4048-6cfe-08dbf0b89242": {
        "sequenceNumber": 4,
        "id": "de0c0a68-bf7a-4048-6cfe-08dbf0b89242",
        "originalSequence": 5,
    }
}
```

I have tried with the the ChatGPT soltions as well. but when solution will be in applied in javascript. It wouldn't work

Comment: Please show what you have tried, saying you did and actually trying are very different things `const output=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input).sort(([,{sequenceNumber:a}],[,{sequenceNumber:b}])=>a-b));` - surprised ChatGPT failed you on this - it's quite simple

Comment: why do you need an order`wha not take an array for it. it is made for ordered elements. objects are ordered by numerical value, positive 32 bit values, like indices first, then all other by insertation order. that means, you need to build a new object, but it is not the way to go,

Comment: Why would I vote to close the question? I find it a perfectly cromulent one